# python - get access to decorator class's "self" inside the inner method

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

Following the example shown here - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-decorator-inside-a-class-in-python/

```py
# creating class A
class A:
    self.someVarInsideClassA = "hello some variable inside class A"

    def Decorators(func):
        def inner(self):
            print("Decoration started.")
            # print(self.someVarInsideClassA) => do not have access here, because "self" is class "B" ❓❓❓❓❓❓❓❓
            func(self)
            print("Decoration of function completed.\n")

        return inner

    @Decorators
    def fun1(self):
        print("Decorating - Class A methods.")


# creating class B
class B(A):
    @A.Decorators
    def fun2(self):
        print("Decoration - Class B methods.")


obj = B()
obj.fun1()
obj.fun2()
```

Looks like the `self` inside `inner` method is referring to `class B`.

Can someone point me in the right direction to access/use variables defined in `Class A` please. TIA

Comment: Of *course* it is referring to an instance of `B`, you are calling the method on a `B` instance. But that doesn't matter, since instances of `B` have access to `A` namespaces, since you inherited from `B`. It really isn't clear to me exactly what you want. Note, the code you have would throw a NameError and never make it past the definition of `class A`.

Comment: `self` refers to an _instance_ not a class. You have not created an `A` instance. For similar reasons `self.someVarInsideClassA = …`  is an error. You should be clear whether you want class or instance variables here. You seem to be mixing them up.

Comment: IOW: " do not have access here, because "self" is class "B"" is just wrong

Comment: That makes sense. I made a `@classmethod` and accessing the instance variable from within the class method, working good for my use case. Thanks y'll 